# Jekyll Liquid: get the link into a variable

Tags: jekyll, liquid

#### Is there a more elegant way to get a particular link for a jekyll page into a variable?:

(*just for example* of my `index.md` startpage, which is not `/` but `/seo/ramble/bla.html`)

This approach works, but feels somewhat overdone... 
    {% capture startpage %}{% link index.md %}{% endcapture %}

But any direct assignment is not possible? E.g. ...

```
{% assign url = link index.md %}
```

...is not working.

Comment: How do you set your root URL? Did you use a variable in index or a baseurl in configuration?

Comment: well, whatever the permalink of my top-level `index.md` is... (from a simple `/` to an explicitly set permalink) ...shall become the value of rooturl. (The `link` function does exactly that, just no assignment possible, as far as I can see)

Comment: Stick to `capture` and `endcapture` [tag](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/tags/) this works and you can do even more magic ...

Answer (score 1):

Your root url is just `site.url` or `{{"/"|absolute_url}}`.

Any of those options should be able to handle the permalink set at `/index.md`.

Comment: Sorry. I clarified my question to say "startpage link", that's not the web root (and as said, the most prominent start page is not just '/' but specifically set for seo-reasons). I need to use that in menu's and stuff... (and I don't want to keep adjusting, hence the „link-lookup“

Comment: None of the above option will give you '/' unless you explicitely sets that up in config, they will take into account `baseurl` so if your site is inside a folder that would be reflected in the url.

Comment: May be an example of your case will clear things out.